# Install Yeoman on OSX

Tags: node.js, macos, yeoman, asp.net-core, dnx

Im setting up Visual Studio Code with ASP.NET 5 on OSX but have errors when installing Yeoman. I am using the following command.

```
npm install -g yo grunt-cli generator-aspnet bower
```

and getting these errors

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/username/.npm/grunt-cli/0.1.13/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/username/.npm/generator-aspnet/0.0.60/package.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error /Users/username/.npm/yo/1.4.7/package.tgz
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "yo" "grunt-cli" "generator-aspnet" "bower"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',
npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/grunt-cli',
npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',
npm ERR!   fstream_stack: 
npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:35:25',
npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:47:53',
npm ERR!      'FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)' ] }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, rmdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/username/npm-debug.log
```

How do I roll back and install without these errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need root access or permissions to install globally!

Try this:

```
sudo npm install -g yo grunt-cli generator-aspnet bower
```